# Reusing one whole fragment in multiple fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, code-reuse

Basically I have multiple tabs and they all refer to the same `.xml` file and pretty much all do the same thing. I want to create one `Fragment` class and then reuse its entire content in the other five `Fragment` classes.

So this is my `template` class - the one that I want all the `fragments` to reuse:

```
public class TabTemplate extends Fragment {
    TimePicker timePickerOne;
    EditText forename;
    EditText surname;
    EditText email;
    EditText telephone;
    Button store;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabfill, container, false);
        timePickerOne = (TimePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timePickers);
        forename = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forename);
        surname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.surname);
        email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        telephone = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.telephone);
        store = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.store);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void populate(){
        ...
    }

}
```

Currently I have something like this:
`TabOne`:

```
public class TabOne extends Fragment {
    TimePicker timePickerOne;
    EditText forename;
    EditText surname;
    EditText email;
    EditText telephone;
    Button store;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabfill, container, false);
        timePickerOne = (TimePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timePickers);
        forename = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forename);
        surname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.surname);
        email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        telephone = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.telephone);
        store = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.store);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void populate(){
        ...
    }

}
```

`Class TabTwo`:

```
public class TabTwo extends Fragment {
    TimePicker timePickerOne;
    EditText forename;
    EditText surname;
    EditText email;
    EditText telephone;
    Button store;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabfill, container, false);
        timePickerOne = (TimePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timePickers);
        forename = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forename);
        surname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.surname);
        email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        telephone = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.telephone);
        store = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.store);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void populate(){
        ...
    }

}
```

As you can see `TabOne` and `TabTwo` are pretty much the same thing and that is why I am trying to reuse everything from the `TabTemplate` class. How do I do this?

Comment: Instead of extending `Fragment`, extend `TabTemplate` ?

Comment: And then what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use only one of your Fragment Classes and do something like this:

```
public class TabTemplate extends Fragment {
    TimePicker timePickerOne;
    EditText forename;
    EditText surname;
    EditText email;
    EditText telephone;
    Button store;

    String argOne;

    // This allows you to tell the Tab Activity Bundle options for whatever you want to do
    public static TabTemplate newInstance(Bundle args){
         TabTemplate fragment = new TabTemplate();
         if(args != null){
            fragment.setArguments(args);
         }
       return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(getArguments() != null){
         // Can retrieve the arguments once it has been created
         Bundle args = getArguments();
         argOne = args.getString("SOME_KEY", "Default Value");
         
        }

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabfill, container, false);
        timePickerOne = (TimePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timePickers);
        forename = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forename);
        surname = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.surname);
        email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);
        telephone = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.telephone);
        store = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.store);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void populate(){
        //... do something with the values here
        forename.setText(argsOne);
        
    }

}
```

Then you can create this fragment multiple times with different `Bundle` params

```
Bundle bundleOne = new Bundle();
bundleOne.putString("SOME_KEY", "Hello Tab One!");
TabTemplate fragmetTabOne = TabTemplate.newInstance(bundleOne);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.someViewId, fragmentTabOne, "TAG").commit();

Bundle bundleTwo = new Bundle();
bundleOne.putString("SOME_KEY", "Hello Tab Two!");
TabTemplate fragmetTabTwo = TabTemplate.newInstance(bundleTwo);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.someOtherViewId, fragmetTabTwo, "TAG").commit();
```

etc.